# how does the while loop iterate assoc array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

how does

```
while($result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){ echo  $result['name'];}
```

iterate all the rows in the table, i mean it should keep printing the first row only  how does it print all rows   i think i am fetching only the array of first row

Comment: I thought the manual would state this, suprisingly NO: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: `$query` is a object holds, among other things, an internal pointer to current row. It is sort of like http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_assoc` returns the current row and iterates the internal pointer

Comment: @bassxzero increments* the internal pointer

Comment: `mysqli_result implements Traversable` (http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) **Traversable interface** - Interface to detect if a class is traversable using `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

Take an example of this loop

```
$i=0;
while($i<5)
{
  // do something
  $i++;
}
```

That loop will only stop when your condition `($i<5)` results in `FALSE`

When you do

```
while($result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
```

This loop willl also keep working as long as your fetch returns a row, which is not `FALSE`. The only different thing happening here is that you are not doing the increment yourself, when `mysqli_fetch_assoc` fetches a row it automatically increments the internal pointer of that result set to the next row so when you call the same function again you get the next row and when there are no more rows left it will return `NULL` which means `$result=NULL;` which will result in `FALSE` and you  will exit the loop.

Comment: so if i made 
$result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)
$result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)
then it will be fetching 2nd row ? or it works in while loop only

Comment: Yes it will be fetching the second row then even without a loop